# Store ABP Autid Log in separate database

Tags: abp

In ABP 4, is it possible to store the Audit Log in a separate database, to save the core database becoming bloated?

For my client Audit Log is nice to have, but not business critical. As such they don't want it backed up with the main database data. Is is possible to configure Audit Logging with a different connection string so that the Audit Log tables can live in a separate database?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible.

In ABP Framework, every module has their own DbContext and different connection name for them.

> See: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Connection-Strings

In your `appsettings.json`, you can set different `ConnectionStrings` for any DbContext.

For audit logging, your settings should be as below for `appsettings.json`.

> Here the documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Audit-Logging#connection-string

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Default": "Server=localhost;Database=MyMainDb;Trusted_Connection=True;",
  "AbpAuditLogging": "Server=localhost;Database=MyAuditLoggingDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

It's so easy to do with ABP :)